# angular2 getting string value out of Observable into local var

Tags: angular, subscribe

I have a function that return an Observable containing a string, like so:

```
retrieveDialingCode(countrycode: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.countries.map(res => res
          .find(country => country.alpha2 === countrycode)
          .countryCallingCodes[0]
      .replace(/\D/g, ''));
}
```

Works great when I use it like this:

```
this.retrieveDialingCode(countrycode).subscribe(res => this.phone.patchValue( { isodialingcode: res } ) );
```

However i only get an Object in dialingCode when I use it like this:

```
const dialingCode = this.retrieveDialingCode(phone.isocountrycode).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'problem' with observables is that they can't easily be converted to values and then used in synchronous code, because you always have to wait for the observable to emit.

Really, you should have all the code that depends on the result of `retrieveDialingCode` ***inside*** the subscribe, as per your first usage.

You may find the pattern

```
let myVar;
myObservable.subscribe(value => myVar = value);
somethingThatUsesMyVar(myVar);
```

will work some of the time, but any delay in resolving `myObservable` means that myVar will not have the expected value.

Note, if `this.countries` is not an observable but an array, you can make `retrieveDialingCode` return the unwrapped value instead of an observable, then no problem.

Comment: Yes I did this before but the async was a problem. Code depending on the results of retrieveDialingCode is somewhat extensive but if that is the only option then i can put it inside the subscribe, a bit ugly IMHO

Comment: Too true, it is annoying. You can pretty it up a bit by putting the downstream code in a method, then `subscribe()` needs only one line inside - a call to the method, passing in the value. (Sorry if that's already obvious).

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the last case your code doesn't return the response, try to use this:

```
let dialingCode;
this.retrieveDialingCode(phone.isocountrycode).subscribe(res => {
  dialingCode = res;
});
```

Here I just store response of `subscribe` to `dialingCode` variable.